# Storing complex time-series in R

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe with several columns:

- state
- county
- year

Then x, y, and z, where x, y, and z are observations unique to the triplet listed above.  I am looking for a sane way to store this in a time series and xts will not let me since there are multiple observations for each time index.  I have looked at the hts package, but am having trouble figuring out how to get my data into it from the dataframe.

(Yes, I did post the same question on Quora, and was advised to bring it here!)

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: A bit.  When I tried to put this in to xts, it choked on it when adding the rownames, since rownames have to be unique.  In this case, there is on row per state-county combination for each year (about 3000).  So I am looking at hts and it appears it should already be an xts before going in.  So I am a bit lost.

Comment: A "time series" is where each row is a different time. From your column names, unless each `year` is a different year, you don't have a time series. If that's the case, then you're probably looking for a `data.frame`.   Is there a reason why you think this is a time series?

Comment: Yes, because it is approximately 3,150 time series bundled up as one datafame.  My thought process is something akin to, "surely there is an object that can bundle this up and make things like plotting easier."  Dealing with it as a data.frame may be the best option.

Comment: Could you provide us with some sample data?

Comment: The complete dataset is available as a CSV here (7.5Mb):

  ftp://ftp.jameshoward.us/pub/howardjp/nfip/tmp/nfip.csv

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to reshape your data so you have a column for every State-County combination. This allows you to construct an xts matrix :

```
require(reshape)
Opt1 <- as.data.frame(cast(Data, Date ~ county + State, value="Val"))
rownames(Opt1) <- Opt1$Date
Opt1$Date <- NULL
as.xts(Opt1)
```

Alternatively, you could work with a list of xts objects, each time making sure that you have the correct format as asked by xts. Same goes for any of the other timeseries packages. A possible solution would be :

```
Opt2 <- 
  with(Data,
    by(Data,list(county,State,year),
      function(x){
        rownames(x) <- x$Date
        x <- x["Val"]
        as.xts(x)
      }
    )
  )
```

Which would allow something like :

```
Opt2[["d","b","2012"]]
```

to select a specific time series. You can use all xts options on that. You can loop through the counties, states and years to construct plots like this one :

[image]

Code for plot :

```
counties <- dimnames(Opt2)[[1]]
states <- dimnames(Opt2)[[2]]
years <- dimnames(Opt2)[[3]]

op <- par(mfrow=c(3,6))
apply(
  expand.grid(counties,states,years),1,
  function(i){
    plot(Opt2[[i[1],i[2],i[3]]],main=paste(i,collapse="-"))
    invisible()
  }
)
par(op)
```

Test-data :

```
Data <- data.frame( State = rep(letters[1:3],each=90),
            county = rep(letters[4:6],90),
            Date = rep(seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"),by="month",length.out=30),each=3),
            Val = runif(270)
)
Data$year <- as.POSIXlt(Data$Date)$year + 1900
```

Comment: I'm partial to the 'list of xts objects' approach. I find working with lists much easier than keeping track of columns. But many folks coming from spreadsheet land like the wide data format because it can be thought of like a spreadsheet.

Comment: @JD Long : depends on how you want to see the data. If you use the wide format, you have a time series with multiple variables. If you use the list, you have a whole set of time series with only one variable. That's why I gave both options.

Comment: I plan to try out both and see what works the best for me in practice.  That's probably why I am so excited about the above post.